# Prevent CGAffineTransfromScale from scaling outside of self.view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipinchgesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransformscale

I am using this method to scale an imageView.

```
-(IBAction)handlePinching:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale,recognizer.scale);
  recognizer.scale = 1;
}
```

How do I prevent my imageView from scaling outside of self.view? I don't want any part of of my imageView to ever scale outside of the self.view.

Answer (score 0):

Set `clipsToBounds` to `YES` on your view to prevent any drawing of subviews outside the bounds of your view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```